# How to slide pages in Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk, slide, swipe

I'm using CORONA SDK. I have a set of pages and I would like to slide between them using swipe left -right. The page contains a set of controls (mostly text)

What is the best way to do this slide/swipe in Corona?

Answer (score 1):

Using touch events.

When the phase of event is "began" (The user just touched the screen), allow the three pages to move (the actual, the forwards and the backwards).

```
if event.phase == "began" then

    page1.canMove = true
    page2.canMove = true
    page3.canMove = true
    initial = {}
    initial.x = event.x
 end
```

If the pages are allowed to move:

```
if page1.canMove == true then
```

Move the three pages according to the x parameter of event.

```
page1.x = page1.x + event.x - initial.x
page2.x = page2.x + event.x - initial.x
page3.x = page3.x + event.x - initial.x
```

when the phase of event is "end" (The user release the finger), remove the permission to move.

```
if event.phase == "end" then
    page1.canMove = false
    page2.canMove = false
    page3.canMove = false
end
```

and adjust the pages, depending on where they are.

I just invented this solution, if someone can contribute to make it more complete :D.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the transitions of the Storyboard

In storyboard, page is a scene, you can add transitions.

```
http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/11/14/introducing-the-storyboard-api/
```

Comment: Actually all pages are similar so I have only one scene. I have read that it's not recommended to use gotoScene in Storyboard for the same scene : http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/34605-storyboard-gotoscene-drops-options-passed-to-if-you-are-going-to-the-same-scene/